# ServiceStack.ORMLite HI/LO Algorithm

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is there an existing way to implement a HI/LO algorithm for my id generation in ORMLite?

I decided to switch from NHibernate to ORMLite and would rather not use AutoIncrement or GUIDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrmLite doesn't have such a function, however, Redis's atomic INCRBY command would give you a source of Id numbers that you could use.